# UnityPlayerActivity uses or overrides a deprecated API

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
D:\Program Files\2020.2.3f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "D:\Program Files\2020.2.3f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-5.6.4.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[
Note: D:\User\Desktop\Anime Files atbp\Games I Make\Downgeon\Temp\gradleOut\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\unity3d\player\UnityPlayerActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
D:\User\Desktop\Anime Files atbp\Games I Make\Downgeon\Temp\gradleOut\unityLibrary\build\.transforms\359017622190da70d6b212815f76ae8b\classes\classes.dex: D8: Type com.unity3d.player.BuildConfig is defined multiple times: D:\User\Desktop\Anime Files atbp\Games I Make\Downgeon\Temp\gradleOut\unityLibrary\build\.transforms\359017622190da70d6b212815f76ae8b\classes\classes.dex, D:\User\Desktop\Anime Files atbp\Games I Make\Downgeon\Temp\gradleOut\launcher\build\intermediates\external_libs_dex\release\out\classes.dex
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
Type com.unity3d.player.BuildConfig is defined multiple times: D:\User\Desktop\Anime Files atbp\Games I Make\Downgeon\Temp\gradleOut\unityLibrary\build\.transforms\359017622190da70d6b212815f76ae8b\classes\classes.dex, D:\User\Desktop\Anime Files atbp\Games I Make\Downgeon\Temp\gradleOut\launcher\build\intermediates\external_libs_dex\release\out\classes.dex
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:132)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:119)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:102)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskRunnable.run(DexMergingTask.kt:445)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade.run(Workers.kt:348)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AdapterWorkAction.execute(AdapterWorkAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:47)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:65)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:98)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:61)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:56)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$3.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:215)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$3.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:210)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:215)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.O.a(:65)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(:11)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:117)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.b: Error: D:\User\Desktop\Anime Files atbp\Games I Make\Downgeon\Temp\gradleOut\unityLibrary\build\.transforms\359017622190da70d6b212815f76ae8b\classes\classes.dex, Type com.unity3d.player.BuildConfig is defined multiple times: D:\User\Desktop\Anime Files atbp\Games I Make\Downgeon\Temp\gradleOut\unityLibrary\build\.transforms\359017622190da70d6b212815f76ae8b\classes\classes.dex, D:\User\Desktop\Anime Files atbp\Games I Make\Downgeon\Temp\gradleOut\launcher\build\intermediates\external_libs_dex\release\out\classes.dex
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.y0.a(:21)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.x0.a(:30)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.x0.a(:10)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.merge(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1990)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.x0.a(:6)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.A0$c.a(:6)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.a.a(:85)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.a.a(:12)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.d(:6)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.b(:1)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.O.a(:30)
    ... 36 more


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:mergeDexRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
     Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
     Type com.unity3d.player.BuildConfig is defined multiple times: D:\User\Desktop\Anime Files atbp\Games I Make\Downgeon\Temp\gradleOut\unityLibrary\build\.transforms\359017622190da70d6b212815f76ae8b\classes\classes.dex, D:\User\Desktop\Anime Files atbp\Games I Make\Downgeon\Temp\gradleOut\launcher\build\intermediates\external_libs_dex\release\out\classes.dex

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
]
stdout[
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 6 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :launcher
WARNING: The option 'android.enableR8' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
It will be removed in a future version of the Android Gradle plugin, and will no longer allow you to disable R8.

> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:generateReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:packageReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:mainApkListPersistenceRelease
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:parseReleaseLocalResources
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseLibraryResources
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJarForPublish
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:parseReleaseLocalResources
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:compileReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:generateReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest
> Task :launcher:prepareLintJar
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseShaders
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseAssets
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :launcher:validateSigningRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:prepareLintJarForPublish
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:bundleLibCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:compileReleaseLibraryResources
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:bundleLibResRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:bundleLibRuntimeRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :launcher:desugarReleaseFileDependencies
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseAssets
> Task :launcher:processReleaseResources

> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac

> Task :launcher:mergeExtDexRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :unityLibrary:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :unityLibrary:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibRuntimeRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileRelease
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseSources
> Task :launcher:lintVitalRelease
> Task :launcher:dexBuilderRelease
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :launcher:stripReleaseDebugSymbols

> Task :launcher:mergeDexRelease FAILED

> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJavaResource
67 actionable tasks: 67 executed
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <a5c628e5460b4ef8b30249ded44d2921>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <a5c628e5460b4ef8b30249ded44d2921>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <a5c628e5460b4ef8b30249ded44d2921>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <a5c628e5460b4ef8b30249ded44d2921>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <a5c628e5460b4ef8b30249ded44d2921>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <a5c628e5460b4ef8b30249ded44d2921>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <a5c628e5460b4ef8b30249ded44d2921>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <a5c628e5460b4ef8b30249ded44d2921>:0)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at <a5c628e5460b4ef8b30249ded44d2921>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <a5c628e5460b4ef8b30249ded44d2921>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <a5c628e5460b4ef8b30249ded44d2921>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <a5c628e5460b4ef8b30249ded44d2921>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <a936841cea2147a2a55ea27843fa46ae>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

Please Help! I really don't know what to do. I've searched a lot and all it did is build only if the Development Build is checked inside Build Settings.

It says the type unity3d.player.BuildConfig is defined multiple times and also have duplicated the classes.dex. Where can I delete that or see that?

I've also tried to add the use the templated on the build settings and edit it out but nothing works. I'm debugging this 3 days now. Please help.

Comment: Here are the paths it is referencing, taken from the error above.  `Type com.unity3d.player.BuildConfig is defined multiple times: D:\User\Desktop\Anime Files atbp\Games I Make\Downgeon\Temp\gradleOut\unityLibrary\build\.transforms\359017622190da70d6b212815f76ae8b\classes\classes.dex, D:\User\Desktop\Anime Files atbp\Games I Make\Downgeon\Temp\gradleOut\launcher\build\intermediates\external_libs_dex\release\out\classes.dex`

Comment: But its on TEMP File which was only created when unity is opened.

Comment: Have you tried clearing out the temp files?  Something may be lingering from a previous failed build attempt that is preventing a clean build of the project.

Comment: @hijinxbassist I've fix it. the problem is my nativeandroid.aar plugin is deprecated that's why I deleted it. But the problem is my Toast won't work now. HAHAHA. Maybe I'll look for another android native plugin. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, unfortunate about Toast though.